# Combining Library and Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, library

I am very new to SharePoint, and I am effectively trying to merge a list and library into one page. I am trying to have the ability to upload 20ish files to a new library (or specified folder) from the same page when creating a new list item. I also want to easily see the associated files when I click on the list item.

My attempts:

1. I have gotten a hyperlink to take you to the folder, but I don't want to have to navigate away or have separate windows open.
2. I have also gotten a library window to show when creating a new form, but I have 2 issues:

   1. This only shows when initialing creating the list, and I would like for it to show every time you open the list.
   2. This also shows every item in the folder, and I only want to show the files associated with that list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi @Capokonski it seems you have multiple questions. Can you potentially split them into separate posts? Otherwise, it sounds like you are asking someone to design an entire solution. You can post a separate question on workflows, on creating/configuring lists, on sending emails, etc. This way you have better chances to get help.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov Thank you for your suggestion, I have edited my question to refocus on my main issue.